# C# WebBrowser control window.name

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, browser-automation

I am trying to automate a site in a WPF application with WebBrowser control.

The site checks for the javascript window.name in each page and throws an error if this does not match with the preset value.

Look at the sample below.

```
var id="1234";
if (window.name != id)
{
  window.open("home.html", id)
}
```

Is there a way to get this value and set it when I create a new WebBrowser object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and my problem is resolved. Hope this may help somebody.

I first navigated the page to a blank page with this code.

```
var html = string.Format(
            "<html><body><h4>Opening ...</h4><script type='text/javascript'>window.open('about:blank', '{0}');</script></body></html>",
            popupWindowName);

        var w = new Browser();
        w.NavigateToString(html);
```

And then in the page is load completed event, I navigated to the original URL.

```
w.Navigate("https://somesite.com/page.aspx",
                null, null, h);
```

The popup window name was changed to what I wanted and the session continuted correctly. This is not a solution to the problem I faced, but it is more like a work around.

I also had to deal with the popups that kept coming. I had handled the NewWindow2 event to handle the popups.